# How do I change syntax highlighting colours in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, syntax-highlighting

In other text editors, one can change the highlighting colour, says, for `comment` of language `PHP`. How do I change individual highlighting colour in Android Studio?

Answer (score 7):

Go to Settings (`Ctrl+Alt+S`) and then go to **IDE Settings > Editor > Colors & Fonts**. From here you can choose either **Language Defaults** or the specific language and edit the comment styling.

You won't be able to edit the default one so you will be prompted to `Save As...`

Comment: How do I `choose [...] the specific language`? I don't see any options or expandable listing of languages, e.g. `PHP` in there. FYI, I am currently using the `Solarized Dark` scheme.

Comment: PHP isn't in there but JAVA, HTML and XML syntax highlighting is.

Comment: Hey I followed your answer and edited the Language Defaults, and edited the name of the theme by `Save as` (which creates a new scheme right?). But they are not applied in the editor. Any suggestions for me?

Answer (score 2):

Today is a **Ctrl+Alt+S** -> **Editor** -> **Color Scheme** -