# Is it possible to avoid special coloration for RegExp in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio

I'm not interested for syntax coloration of RegExp in Android Studio but I would prefer if they have the same coloration like normal string. For example, when I type:

```
Pattern p = compile("[A-Z]");
```

The regular expression inside double-quotes is colorized differently than a normal string.

I've found it's possible to customize the coloration of each element of regexp but i've not found a way to avoid specific coloration for them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change syntax highlighting colours in Android Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27150674/how-do-i-change-syntax-highlighting-colours-in-android-studio)

Comment: I want to completely avoid regexp coloration and that Android Studio consider them as simple String
I do not want to customize coloration for regexp.